# Choose: Fuels were formed underground (over - in - from - for) millions of years

Tags: prepositions

I got confused with this question:

> Choose: Fuels were formed underground (over - in - from - for) millions of years.

I'm puzzled between (over) and (in).

Comment: Does it help to imagine "the course of" added? over the course of millions of years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition "in" is used for periods of time such as in 6 days, in 2 weeks, in 1990, etc.,while in addition to this use, over is used also to mean above, more or to refer to an extended period of time such as over two hundred years ago. So over millions of years is the most appropriate phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"Over" and "in" can both be used to talk about something that happens fairly continuously for a period of time.

> We have seen a rise in attacks over/in the last few months.
>   We hope to see a decrease in returns over/in the next few weeks.

So, with the basics established, we find that these don't really help us in this case!

The trick here is to decide which one means "during", as that is the meaning of the sentence (note that "during" is not grammatical in this sentence).

> Fuels were forming underground "during" millions of years.

If you can decide which one is most synonymous with "during", your doubt should resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the formation of fuel takes a very, very long time, like millions of years. Therefore: Fuels were formed over millions of years. On the other hand: Elephants lived in Africa for millions of years. Each of them doesn't live for a very long time, but there was a long time in which generation after generation lived. "From" would require a point in time, like: Fuels were formed from the early Pleistocene onwards.